# Write Emergency Stop button in C# serial interface

Tags: c#, serial-port, backgroundworker

I am writing a Serial interface to communicate with the controller which controls the short link of my robot. I am afraid that it will hit the wall when it is moving, so I want to create a emergency stop button so that when  I press it the robot will stop move immediately and only can keep working if I send release command "!MG".

For now I have two sets buttons for both short link and long link, ie. CW and CCW. And I want the stop button to stop both links from moving at the same time. How do I achieve this by using backgroundWorker?I don't know how to arrange the code in DoWork because long link and short link will only move if the button CW or CCW gets clicked, which makes it hard to monitor it in the DoWork

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e){}
```

here is a sample of my shortLinkCW button, and I used another method 
      ShortLinkCW(string Angle)
to cover all the commands should be done in CW button,

```
  private void ShortLinkCW(string Angle)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        String dtn = dt.ToShortTimeString();
        String angle_string = Angle;
        double angle = Convert.ToDouble(angle_string);
        int encoder = 0;
        String encoder_string = encoder.ToString();
        String data = "!PR 1 " + encoder_string + '\r';
        while (angle > 60)
        {

            encoder = Convert.ToInt32(60 * 22.76);
            encoder_string = encoder.ToString();
            data = "!PR 1 " + encoder_string + '\r';
            shortPort.Write(data);
            angle = angle - 60;
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
        encoder = Convert.ToInt32(angle * 22.76);
        encoder_string = encoder.ToString();
        data = "!PR 1 " + encoder_string + '\r';
        shortPort.Write(data);
        txtReceive.AppendText("[" + dtn + "] " + "Sent: " + data + "\n");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        getEncoderValueAndCoordinates();

    }
```

and for the CW button, I just call this method.

```
    private void ShortLinkClockwise_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (shortPort == null)
            txtReceive.AppendText("ShortPort isn't open yet!" + "\n");
        else
            esSCW(ShortLinkAngle.Text, "shortCW");
    }
```

Any suggestion for me to monitor the movement of links in the Do_work and stop them whenever  I want ([see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDFkH.png))?

One thing just bumped out my head is that, if I can somehow notice CW or CWW button gets clicked in the Do_work, and then I can call the function like ShortLinkCW(string angle), then stop it whenever necessary. is it possible?

Comment: Why do you need to sleep?  You need to write code that is Async so you aren't blocked.  The blocking will prevent you from sending immediate message.  If you want to slowly change the angle user a timer event instead of going to sleep.

Comment: @jdweng  does this mean that  if I use the timer event I don't need the background blocker any more?

Comment: An Asynchronous program requires only one block in main function.  A Form application has a built in block in the form class that the user never sees.  A console application requires adding a block so program doesn't exit.  A Background work doesn't require any blocks and continues to run until the class is disposed provided the main function doesn't terminate.

Comment: By the way, you don;t even need a timer in a form class.  You can call the Do_Work over and over again.  You can pass the background worker commands in the EventArgs so you can have a start and stop command.  See following example : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/waw3xexc(v=vs.110).aspx